# Layout where header has fixed position, content is in center, and user navigation on centent's right

Tags: css, html

I have managed to get **header** at the top, and **content** at the center. But I did get stuck with placing **user-navigation** div at the right of the content. I have tried using `position:relative`, but what happens it appears below content's div, but on the right though, and also when I scroll down the view, it appears on top of the **header**.

So how do I solve this? Thanks!

## Updated

This is how it should look visually:
[image]

Comment: Hey OP, after 7 years and now with lots of reputation under your belt, you will probably see that this question needs a bit of attention: it is of low quality (no code provided - can't reproduce / unclear what you're asking) and has two answers, none of which is marked accepted. Would you mind either marking one of these answers as accepted, answering it yourself or even deleting the question? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="nav">
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>

#header { position:fixed; height:100px; }

#nav { float:right; margin-top:100px; }

#content { overflow:auto; margin-top:100px; }
```

Should work unless I didn't understand.

Comment: Hi, I have attached a picture to my post how layout should look visually

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the navigation to be inside the content and on top at the bottom right you should do the following. Set the content's position to relative, and then set the navigation's to absolute. Then for the navigation set the position like so -

```
#nav { position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; }
```

Does that work?